# Link to external file in LibreOffice

Tags: java, libreoffice

I use the LibreOffice API to convert an Excel file to a PDF. It works well but what is rather bothering me is that when I load the Excel file, I get a pop up dialog that asked for refreshing the file because of links to an external file.

How can I turn off this dialog popping up. I would prefer if I can set this configuration in Java and not in LibreOffice itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To skip the prompt, set the option `Tools -> Options -> LibreOffice Calc -> General -> Updating / Update links when opening` to either "Always" or "Never".  It would be easiest to set this option manually.

To set options programmatically, see the code in section 10.7.3 of [Andrew Pitonyak's macro document](http://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php).  Andrew notes that the Options dialog is very complicated.